# Get autocomplete suggestions from a column in another worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a column in one worksheet, where I have to choose one entry from a long list of possibilities that are stored in another sheet. Is it possible to link the two columns so that autocomplete pulls suggestions from that other sheet's column? If so, how?

Comment: look into data validation.  It is in the data tab.  Then choose list.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error saying "This type of reference cannot be used in a data validation function. Change the reference to a single cell, or use the reference with a worksheet function, such as =SUM(A1:E5)"

Comment: The list I'm trying to use is =[materials.xls]tblMaterials!$B$3:$B$901, so B3:B901 in the tblMaterials sheet of the materials.xls file

Comment: you stated that it was in another sheet not another workbook.  See [THIS SITE](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal05.html) for work arounds.